# Using a raster image as tiled background in a scaled svg

Tags: html, svg

I am stuck trying to get the following to work:

- An embedded svg picture, in an html5 document.
- It has a single polygon (a triangle), taking all the svg viewport: ◤
- This should extend to take full height of its container.

So far so good, this example does the job:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 5em; height: 5em;
  resize: both; overflow: hidden; // so we can play with it in demo
}

#triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: #00f;
  pointer-events: none;           // so we can grab the resize handle
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg id="triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="0,0 0,10 10,0" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Try grabbing the resize handle to see how the triangle reacts to changes in container size.

There is just one last thing I miss and cannot figure out how to do:

- The triangle must be textured using a raster image (png file)
- That texture must not be scaled.

So far my best attempt was using the initial coordinate system (no viewPort directive), to apply a filter to a square, like this:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 5em; height: 5em;
  resize: both; overflow: hidden; // so we can play with it in demo
}
#triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;           // so we can grab the resize handle
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg id="triangle" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <filter id="Tiled">
        <feImage xlink:href="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/filters/smiley.png"
                 x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" result="texture"/>
        <feTile in="texture" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      </filter>
    </defs>

    <rect filter="url(#Tiled)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Again, try resizing the image using the (invisible) handle at the bottom-right corner: the background texture gets tiled.

**Thus the question:**

The second example works thanks to the `width="100%"`. However, polygons do not accept percentage coordinates.

→ How to achieve the tiling behavior of the second example, but on a dynamically sized polygon like first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a polygon to clip the rect to get the effect you want don't you?

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 5em; height: 5em;
  resize: both; overflow: hidden; // so we can play with it in demo
}
#triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;           // so we can grab the resize handle
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg id="triangle" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <filter id="Tiled">
        <feImage xlink:href="https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/filters/smiley.png"
                 x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" result="texture"/>
        <feTile in="texture" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
      </filter>
      <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <polygon points="0,0 0,1 1,0" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>

    <rect clip-path="url(#clip)" filter="url(#Tiled)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing, I had tried mixing filters and patterns but I had completely overlooked clip path. It's the first time I write some svg myself and it's still hard to put all pieces together.